# ansible run role against host name that is returned from a local script

Tags: ansible

I have a local script that returns to me the name of the host I need to do an install on. How can I take the result of this script and use it to set the host? Here is an example of the kind of code I thought I could write to achieve this:

```
---
 - hosts: localhost
   roles:
    - getHostScript # running this sets a variable called hostname

 - hosts: "{{{hostvars.localhost.hostname}}"
   roles:
    - install # this runs the install script
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `add_host` module to the new host to your inventory, and then target that host in another play:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - getHostScript # running this sets a variable called hostname
  tasks:
    - name: add new host to inventory
      add_host:
        name: "{{ hostname }}"
        groups: target

- hosts: target
  roles:
   - install # this runs the install script
```

Here I'm adding the new host to a group named `target` so that I can just refer to the group name, rather than needing to know the actual host name in the following play.